# Intuitive explanation of p-norm in finite and infinite dimensinos

Tags: geometry, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

I am not a mathematician, so very rigorous treatment with things that only a math major learns will not suffice here.
I want to learn about p-norms and i can't quite get the intuition behind them. I am talking about what they actually mean and what their (geometric or not) consequences are.
For example, in this wikipedia page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions
I can't undestand why for example the unit circle in L1 is a rhombus and why is it a square for p=infinity. I think not understanding these has to do with the fact that i have no **intuition regarding the p-norms and the geometric consequences of the way that we defined them**. And lastly, why would someone define the norm in a way that p is not equal to 2?
Thank you!

Comment: You seem to misunderstand something : the "$p$-norm" as you say has nothing to do about the dimension of the space being $p$. It is defined in every finite dimension.

Comment: @Captain Lama , wow you are right!i edited!

Answer (score 1):

For the form of the sphere for $l^p$ norms, well, it's not really conceptual, you just look at the definition.

For the $l^1$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ for instance, $(x,y)$ is a unit vector iff $|x| + |y| = 1$. If $x$ and $y$ are positive, this means $y=1-x$, so the intersection of the unit sphere with the first quadrant is the line $y= 1-x$. You can check the other quadrants to see that in total it makes a square.

Same thing for $l ^\infty$: $(x,y)$ is a unit vector iff $\max(|x|, |y|) = 1$, which means that $x=\pm 1$ and $ -1 \leqslant y\leqslant 1$, or $y=\pm 1$ and $ -1 \leqslant x\leqslant 1$ : this is also a square.

As for why someone would define these norms, I guess the answer will not be very satisfactory in finite dimension, since it is well-known that all the norms are equivalent, so indeed you can't gain much by considering all these "exotic" norms (they are not *very* exotic, though).

But first, some problems naturally involve powers that are not squares, and in that case the $l^p$ norm may be more natural to solve the problem.

Second and more important, these are baby cases for the *real* $l^p$ norms, those in infinite dimension. And they are very important, because this time they are not equivalent, so they don't give the same answers. Some objects will have a finite $l^p$ norm for some $p$ and some will not, so you have to choose your $p$ according to the situation, and $p=2$ will not suffice.

Comment: Thanks for explaining how we get the plots from the wikipedia article. But, in reality, i want a more general intuition about the consequences(geometric if possible) of having a different norm.

Comment: There is basically none because they are equivalent.

Comment: But if there are no consequences, then why change p?

Comment: As I said in my answer, in finite dimension it doesn't matter, I don't think anyone really cares about the $l^p$ norm in finite dimension except for undergrad teachers because it makes for a nice elementary exercise. Usually people just say "let $||\cdot||$ be a norm" and don't bother choosing one. In infinite dimension, of course, this is a whole other matter.

Comment: Yes, i understand this about finite dimensions, but what are the consequences in infinite dimensions? What changes there?